# Ruby convert Mysql timestamp to Mysql datetime

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am trying to import data from a DB to another. The source DB has TIMESTAMP (mysql) the destination has DATETIME (mysql). I am trying something like that:

```
start_at = DateTime.at(row['QA_CONF_START_STAMP']) #start_at
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if conversion is expressly required in this case, as the two values should be equivalent.

Since you're not retrieving the original data using a model, it's coming through as a raw string. The easiest way to interpret that is:

```
DateTime.parse(row['QA_CONF_START_STAMP'])
```